# How to define complications for multiple watch faces in one app?

Tags: android, wear-os, watchface, android-wear-complication

I have two watch faces (two services) in one app. Everthing works fine, I have different styles for each watch face.

My problem is the complications. If I change the complications in watch face No.1, it works. If I change the complications in watch face No.2, the change is visible in No.1 and there are no complications in No.2.

It looks like the information about the complications the user selects, both in watch face No.1 and in No.2, are stored in the same place.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

PS: Please excuse my writing style. I'm from Germany. :-) And sorry for the explanation of the issue. I'm a noob.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "change the complications"? Do you mean select a different data provider? Do you have different complication IDs defined for the complications in the different watch faces?

Comment: Hi. Yes, when the user changes the data provider like time, world clock, steps etc. For the second watch face I made a copy of the activity. And while trying to find the reason for that problem I changed all IDs, variable names... everything. I think I have a lot of redundant code now :-) but still no solution.

Comment: And thanks for editing.

Comment: And I made a copy of the service. Not only of the activity.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you activate the complications for both of your watch faces

Comment: Hi TofferJ! I can not work on it until the weekend, but then I will write immediately